# Lipschitz funtion satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}n f(\frac{x}{n})=0, \forall\ x\in [-1,1]$. How to show it is differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Lipschitz funtion satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}n f(\frac{x}{n})=0, \forall\ x\in [-1,1]$. How to show it is differentiable at $x=0$?

Clearly, $f(0)=0$. But how to show $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$?

Answer (score 3):

We fix $x\in (0;1)$ and compute for $\frac{x}{n+1}<y<\frac{x}{n}$
$$ \left\vert \frac{f(y)}{y} - \frac{f(x/n)}{(x/n)} \right\vert
\leq \frac{\vert f(y) - f(x/n)\vert (x/n)}{y (x/n)} + \frac{\vert f(x/n)\vert \cdot \vert x/n-y \vert}{y(x/n)}
\leq \frac{[C(x/n)+ \vert f(x/n)\vert] \vert x/n - y\vert}{y (x/n)}
\leq [C (x/n)+\vert f(x/n) \vert] \frac{(1/n-1/(n+1)) \vert x \vert}{(x/(n+1)) (x/n) }
= [C(x/n)+\vert f(x/n) \vert] \frac{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}{\frac{x}{n(n+1)}} 
\leq \frac{C}{n} + \frac{f(x/n)}{x}.$$
Furthermore, by assumption
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x/n)}{(x/n)}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{nf(x/n)}{x} =\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nf(x/n)}{x}=0. $$

Combine the two and conclude.